# Justified footnotes

Tags: footnotes

I'd like to have the footnotes justified in the following way:
[image]

I tried to use [footmisc](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/footmisc) and also the \deffootnote command from [scrextend](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/scrextend) package but couldn't figure it out. I guess with \deffootnote one should set the  to the width of the \footnotemark and  to zero but I can't figure out how to actually realise this.

Also, I use the article class and would prefer to keep it.

Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blindtext\footnote{\blindtext}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[scrextend](https://ctan.org/pkg/scrextend) makes several of [KOMA-script](https://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script)'s features available for other classes than its own, see page 275 in the manual. The `\deffootnote` command is described at page 91.

[image]

To get the layout you are asking for, all parameters are set to the same value, save for the second, which is the note indent from the left margin. `[0pt]` set the note flush to the left margin. In my opinion, you should also remove the `\textsuperscript`, because it is much nicer to have the footnote number in ordinary font in the footnote itself.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\deffootnote[1.5em]{0em}{1.5em}{%
    \makebox[1.5em][l]{\textsuperscript{\thefootnotemark}}%
    }
\begin{document}

\blindtext\footnote{\blindtext}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Cheers! I myself prefer the same layout you suggested but unfortunately I have to follow a style guide forced upon me. Many thanks!

Comment: @JDecou You have my deepest compassion :)